# how to use a <p> tag as an exception

Tags: html, css

I'm working with a `theme.css` that defines the `p#btt` (back to top) button with a `margin` of `4px`, so it appears centered (top to bottom) on a stationary ribbon on the bottom of the page. I also have a `procedureStyles.css` that only affects procedure pages, and it defines regular `<p>` tags with a `margin` of `0px`.

On the procedure pages, the back to top button is using the `margin` of `0px`, when I would like it to use the 4px `margin`. Changing the `theme.css` is difficult because it's managed by another department.

What I'm wondering: is there a way to use the regular `<p>` tag with the `margin` of `0px` on every `<p>` tag EXCEPT in the case of the btt `4px` definition?

I found ways to alter the `p#btt`, but I'm trying to avoid that.

Comment: Add the margin to the button?

Comment: can you share some code?

Comment: from the theme: p#btt a {margin:4px;}

Comment: from the procedureStyles p {margin: 0px; }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the `:not()`, something like this?

```css
p {
  background: yellow
}
p#btt  {
  margin: 4px
}
p:not(#btt) {
  margin: 0
}
```

```html
<p>Foo Bar</p>
<p>Foo Bar</p>
<p>Foo Bar</p>
<p>Foo Bar</p>
<p>Foo Bar</p>
<p>Foo Bar</p>
<p>Foo Bar</p>
<p>Foo Bar</p>
<p>Foo Bar</p>
<p>Foo Bar</p>
<p>Foo Bar</p>
<p id="btt">Foo Bar</p>
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much. Clearly, I hadn't searched with the right wording. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I'm new at this. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Use inline styles on the HTML of your paragraph if you are completely against changing the stylesheets. This will avoid changing any CSS files and/or using JavaScript.

```
<p id="btt" style="margin:4px;"></p>
```